# How to loop images using map method in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am working on react project in that I have `App.js` that is parent for `Child.js`. In my project I have public folder In that I have assets folder in that I have images folder in this folder I have all images. I am trying to loop all these images. But it is showing syntax error.

The error is shown like this

> ./src/App/App.js Module not found: Can't resolve
>   '.public/assets/images' in src/App/App.js

This is **App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

function Employers() {
    return (
        <div className='container-fluid'>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-12'>
                    <div className='Main'>
                       <Child></Child>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

This is **Child.js**

```
import React from 'react';


function Child() {
    const imageShell = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten', 'eleven', 'tweleve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen', 'fifteen', 'sixteen'];
    const loopImages = imageShell.map(function (images, i) {
        return <img src={require(".public/assets/images/" + images + ".jpg")} alt='imageLooping'></img>
    });
    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-12'>
                    <div className='imageClassOne'>
                        {loopImages}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Child
```

You think I am not clear with my doubt please put a comment

Comment: Probably path error here: .public/assets/images/. Shouldn't it be `./public/assets/images/`

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a typo

You forgot a `/`

```
// forgot / here
require("./public/assets/images/" + images + ".jpg")
```